# Rust How to Get Contents of Arc

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I have a class that contains a `TcpStream` - that `TcpStream` isn't guaranteed to be there - so I originally used `Option` but found that `Arc` uses thread safety - and since I am running async tasks - it is possible that this could cause some threading issues. So I wrapped up my `Arc<TcpStream>` but am having issues getting the data...

```
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
enum ConnectionError {
    ConnectError(usize),
    SendError(usize),
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct Connection {
    stream: Arc<TcpStream>,
    loc: usize,
}

impl Connection {
    async fn connect(loc:usize) -> Result<Connection, ConnectionError> {
        println!("Connecting");
        
        let stream = TcpStream::connect("3.77.107.247:86").await.map_err(|_| ConnectionError::ConnectError(loc))?;
        //stream.write_all(b"Hello World\n").await;

        Ok( Connection2 {
            stream: Arc::new(stream),
            loc: loc,
            }
        )
    }
    async fn Send(mut connection: Connection, string: String) -> Result<Connection2, ConnectionError> {
        println!("Count: {},", Arc::weak_count(&connection.stream));
        if let Some(x) = Arc::get_mut(&mut connection.stream) {
            x.write_all(b"HELLO").await.map_err(|_| ConnectionError::SendError(connection.loc))?;
        }
        else {
            println!("Unable to send message");
        }
        Ok( connection )
    }
}
```

I always end up with an unexpected output:

> Unable to send message
> thread 'tokio-runtime-worker' panicked at 'called `Option::unwrap()` on a `None` value', src\main.rs:292:58
> note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace

Which indicates to me that my `Arc` get_mut is null...

I have printed out the `Weak count` as shown, but that output is 0.

Any guidance?

Comment: Note: The IP is public - nothing is on it - and it gets changed when I reset the instance (AWS EC2 instance) :) Not too concerned

Comment: Erm, what? Not sure what you are asking

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I misread at first.

Comment: `get_mut()` will fail if there are other owners, determined by `strong_count()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have a class that contains a TcpStream - that TcpStream isn't guaranteed to be there - so I originally used Option but found that Arc uses thread safety - and since I am running async tasks - it is possible that this could cause some threading issues. So I wrapped up my Arc but am having issues getting the data...

That's... probably the wrong solution entirely? And the two are not even interchangeable, where's the

> I have a class that contains a TcpStream - that TcpStream isn't guaranteed to be there

bit gone? An Arc can not do that, it always contains something.

`Option` is thread-safe, it can only exist in one thread at a time. `Arc` is thread-safe, it can be shared between threads. The way you've designed this, you can have multiple `Connection` in different threads sharing the same underlying tcp stream, which sounds like a terrible idea.

Furthermore, `Arc` can not be mutated directly (unless it specifically has a strong count of 1 which is apparently not the case here), instead you need to use some sort of thread-safe "interior mutability" container which can yield a mutable reference from an immutable one, usually a [`Mutex`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html) or an [`RWLock`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.RwLock.html).

Here I don't see the point of either the `Arc` or the `Option`:

- straight sharing a `TcpStream` between multiple `Connection` sounds like a bad idea, some sort of pooling or multiplexing might be OK but I'd want very explicit and wilful support for it, not just sending shit in the pipe and hoping it comes out the other end in an acceptable state, interleaving messages sounds like a recipe for disaster.
- `Arc` can not be empty, so the

  > I have a class that contains a TcpStream - that TcpStream isn't guaranteed to be there

  justification for an Option makes no sense.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood the structs then... my purpose is to have 1) a Connection that is either 1.a) connected or 1.b) Not connected. If it is 1.b) not connected, then the 2.a) tcpstream will be None otherwise 2.b) it will exist. Thus, I created a struct that contains a `TcpStream` that **COULD** exist, but isn't guaranteed to. I only need 1 `TcpStream` per connection. In generality, I just want to have multiple `TcpStream`s that can all be accepting/sending out msg's async'ly. I maintain that my `Connection` will never be empty, but the `TcpStream` inside my Connection could be.

Comment: Given that `Arc` is incorrect -- why would `Option` be wrong here? Or better question - what would be the best data container to hold my `TcpStream`?

Comment: @impression7vx I'm just saying that an `Option` makes no sense based off of the code you show here, and the fact that you *replaced* the `Option` with an `Arc`: the point of an `Option` is to hold something or nothing, but the code of your `connect` function always fills the structure, so there's no `Nothing` involved anywhere I can see and I don't see the point of using an `Option`. You could obviously create an unconnected connection which has to be connected as a latter point but... why would you do that?

Comment: I suppose I see your point - for some reason I was thinking that a TcpStream might close and thus I would need to check if the TcpStream was `None` and then associate from there.

Comment: Erm I recall why I did it - to be fair, I’m brand new to Rust  but I did it so I could use ‘clone’ as I need to implement that feature for TcpStream. If I wrap up my tcpstream, I can use clone and then get the associated data. With this new information, maybe you can [point me in the right direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66766530/rust-how-to-implement-clone-for-an-imported-class)

Comment: The problem is that unless you implement `Clone` by hand and somehow duplicate the TcpConnection you'll be back to what I was talking about initially: two `Connection` using the same TCP stream, which doesn't seem like a very good idea, at least without something in the middle which ensures the queries / requests / … are properly multiplexed over the single connection.